# Unitils dataset - insert into sybase datetime column

Tags: datetime, dataset, sybase, unitils

I have a unitils dataset attempting to enter data into a sybase datetime column, but it errors when I try and run the unit tests.

I cannot find anything online about inserting dates, so I tried declaring it as a String in the same way as the other columns, but I get the error:

```
org.unitils.core.UnitilsException: Error inserting test data from DbUnit dataset for method etc etc
    at org.unitils.dbunit.DbUnitModule.insertDataSet(DbUnitModule.java:156)
    at org.unitils.dbunit.DbUnitModule$DbUnitListener.beforeTestSetUp(DbUnitModule.java:556)
    at org.unitils.core.Unitils$UnitilsTestListener.beforeTestSetUp(Unitils.java:273)
    at org.unitils.UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner$TestListenerInvokingMethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner.java:151)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:84)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:49)
    at org.unitils.UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner.invokeTestMethod(UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner.java:95)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.runMethods(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:61)
    at org.unitils.UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner.access$000(UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner.java:44)
    at org.unitils.UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner$1.run(UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner.java:62)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:34)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:44)
    at org.unitils.UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner.run(UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: org.unitils.core.UnitilsException: Error while executing DataSetLoadStrategy
    at org.unitils.dbunit.datasetloadstrategy.impl.BaseDataSetLoadStrategy.execute(BaseDataSetLoadStrategy.java:46)
    at org.unitils.dbunit.DbUnitModule.insertDataSet(DbUnitModule.java:230)
    at org.unitils.dbunit.DbUnitModule.insertDataSet(DbUnitModule.java:153)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: org.dbunit.dataset.datatype.TypeCastException: Error casting value for table 'USER' and column 'SUSPEND_SD'
    at org.dbunit.operation.AbstractBatchOperation.execute(AbstractBatchOperation.java:202)
    at org.dbunit.operation.CompositeOperation.execute(CompositeOperation.java:78)
    at org.unitils.dbunit.datasetloadstrategy.impl.CleanInsertLoadStrategy.doExecute(CleanInsertLoadStrategy.java:45)
    at org.unitils.dbunit.datasetloadstrategy.impl.BaseDataSetLoadStrategy.execute(BaseDataSetLoadStrategy.java:44)
    ... 20 more
```

The only line inserting a date in my dataset is:

```
<USER ID="4" FULL_NAME="user3" SUSPEND_SD="25/12/2011 00:00" SUSPEND_ED="25/12/2013 00:00" PASSWORD="password3"/>
```

Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it turns out it has to be in exactly the format YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS", for example "2011-01-01 02:00:00".

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how unitils works but assuming your dataset is editable why not change the dates to yyyy/mm/dd format.

That java stack mentions casting, and that'll be a failure getting dd/mm/yyyy to datetime I'd think.

Alternatively the middleware probably has some date config means - you can probably tell it dates are British (it might even be regional settings?)

Comment: Thanks, but still the same error :(. I think it is because it is being declared as a String, but how else can I insert something into the date column from the dataset??