# insert empty date on unitils dataset

Tags: date, testing, dataset, unitils

I got error similar to this: [Unitils dataset - insert into sybase datetime column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14121793/unitils-dataset-insert-into-sybase-datetime-column)

My case is that need to insert a date value that is empty. Empty String does not do the thing. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

If you leave your date element off of the row definition, it won't add anything in that field. So with a table definition of:

```
CREATE TABLE Table (
  id          INTEGER,
  name        VARCHAR,
  birthDate   DATE
);
```

create a row like this:

```
<table id="3" name="Katie"/>
<table id="4" name="Christie" birthDate="2001-04-22"/>
```

to load an empty date in ID 3.